# How to select which request from the queue to get the resource in Simpy

Tags: python, simpy

I am working on simulating a scheduling algorithm in Simpy. What I need to do is to choose from the queue which requests to get the resource. I have read the examples provided on the Simpy website and the documentation. However, I could not find anything regarding selecting requests from the queue to serve. Priority resources don't satisfy my requirement too. I also searched the questions on stack overflow, but I could not find something similar to what I am trying to do. I thought about generating the request objects and storing them in an array, and after deciding which one must be served, I requested the resource. But that does not seem valid to me as I am trying to simulate task scheduling.

Is it possible to override the queueing behavior in Simpy to achieve this task?
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to tackle this depends on the kind of scheduler you want to implement. If it shall just be a simple priority based scheduling with fixed priorities you can use the `PriorityResource` instead of `Resource`. Same with preemption but then you have you to use the `PreemptiveResoure`.

If your scheduling strategy is more complicated you have to implement your own resource, request and queue type.

```
class MyOwnPriorityRequest(Request):

# just changed the priority to float type, you can do of course more sophisticated stuff here
    def __init__(
        self, resource: 'Resource', priority: float = 0, preempt: bool = True
    ):
        self.priority = priority
        """The priority of this request. A smaller number means higher
        priority."""

        self.preempt = preempt
        """Indicates whether the request should preempt a resource user or not
        (:class:`PriorityResource` ignores this flag)."""

        self.time = resource._env.now
        """The time at which the request was made."""

        self.key = (self.priority, self.time, not self.preempt)
        """Key for sorting events. Consists of the priority (lower value is
        more important), the time at which the request was made (earlier
        requests are more important) and finally the preemption flag (preempt
        requests are more important)."""

        super().__init__(resource)
```

Next we need to provide our queue type:

```
class MyOwnSortedQueue(list):
    """Queue for sorting events by their :attr:`~PriorityRequest.key`
    attribute.

    """

    def __init__(self, maxlen: Optional[int] = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.maxlen = maxlen
        """Maximum length of the queue."""

    def append(self, item: Any) -> None:
        """Sort *item* into the queue.

        Raise a :exc:`RuntimeError` if the queue is full.

        """
        if self.maxlen is not None and len(self) >= self.maxlen:
            raise RuntimeError('Cannot append event. Queue is full.')

        super().append(item)
        super().sort(key=lambda e: e.key, reverse=True)
```

And finally you can implement your individual resource:

```
class MyOwnPriorityResource(Resource):

    PutQueue = MyOwnSortedQueue

    GetQueue = list

    def __init__(self, env: Environment, capacity: int = 1):
        super().__init__(env, capacity)

    if TYPE_CHECKING:

        def request(
            self, priority: int = 0, preempt: bool = True
        ) -> MyOwnPriorityRequest:
            """Request a usage slot with the given *priority*."""
            return PriorityRequest(self, priority, preempt)

        def release(  # type: ignore[override] # noqa: F821
            self, request: PriorityRequest
        ) -> Release:
            """Release a usage slot."""
            return Release(self, request)

    else:
        request = BoundClass(MyOwnPriorityRequest)
        release = BoundClass(Release)
```

Essentially thats it. Now you can implement your own selection strategy in your `MyOwnSortedQueue`class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. This is precisely what I am looking for. Regarding the priority of the requests, is it possible to assign them after generating them? And Is it possible to change it during the runtime to change the order of the requests in the queue? or

Comment: Yes of course. In the given example I replaced the input queue, what allows to define the order when putting items to the queue. When you want to order the elements in the queue, when one item is requested, you need to overwrite the GetQueue with your own type instead of list. This type is required to allow index access and offer some pop() and append() methods. I.e.. the interface needs to be partly compatible with list. Then you can implement your logic in the pop(). Thought, this needs be very efficient as it will be called a lot of times, otherwise your perfomance will be very bad.